# jQuery Mobile, navigation with query strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

In my jQuery Mobile project, I have a page that shows a slide's content. The content is dependent of the query string.

On opening of the first slide by visiting #slidePage?sec=0&page=0 -> It works

On the same slide page I have a link for  #slidePage?sec=0&page=1 ( the second page). --> this link doesn't work

Seems that the browser or jQuery is convinced that it is the same page and do not navigate .

What can I do ?

I tried to disable ajax but that didn't work.

Comment: you are putting querystring AFTER hash-tags??? I dont know what you want to do, you need to put some source here or to jsfiddle, but im quite sure that the problem is with the order of your querystring and hashtags

Comment: @Luke Here is a [link to a simplified version of what I am trying to](http://jsfiddle.net/N7Z9e/750/) I want to keep passing increments of the number as query string argument to the SAME page (jquery page i.e. a DIV with data-role=page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query strings (to internal pages) are not supported by jQuery mobile.

There are a number of jQuery mobile plugins that could be useful to enable this feature.

See:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/pages/page-scripting.html

Answer (score 2):

@Cameron Askew has just released a brilliant JQuery (Mobile) plugin that enables you to send QueryString parameters between pages:

https://github.com/CameronAskew/jquery.mobile.paramsHandler

Comment: Thanks, I threw it together rather quickly & will try to make improvements if time ever permits, especially if people ask for them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this just with jquery mobile. On pagebeforeshow simply read the data-url attribute that jquery mobile adds to the page. Then just add the code to do what you need to do with the querystring.

**This will only work with Ajax navigation rather than multi-page.**

```
<a href="your-page.html?id=1" data-role="button">Show page "two" querystring id=1</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#your-page-id-here').on('pagebeforeshow',function(){

    console.log($(this).data("url"))

});
</script>
```